# How to generate the LoRa App key and App EUI

Tags: lorawan

LoRa appKey and appEUI can i randomly generate ? or anything else...

Example:
AppEUI (8 bytes, example): 424152414E490000 (random value)

Appkey (16 bytes, example):424152414E492044455349474E000000 (random value)

Comment: Please add some context, what network, what node, OTAA or ABP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use random AppKeys for your devices. (It is recommended that every device has a different AppKey.) Please note that the AppKey you provision on the LoRaWAN network server must be the same as the one your LoRaWAN end device is personalized with.

The purpose of the AppEUI is to identify the Join Server of your home network. When your device sends a Join Request to the network server it will forward it to the Join Server of your device. Therefore, it is essential the you personalize your end device with a proper AppEUI.
However, in case your network server is not connected to any external Join Server and processes all Join Requests by itself, the AppEUI is not used for anything and you can use a random EUI. It is still important that the AppEUI provisioned on the network server is the same as the one the device is personalized with.